# BFS Surrounding

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

Given an NxN grid of 0s, 1s, and 2s, find out whether 1s or 2s is surrounded. Being surrounded means that 1s is surrounded by 2s or that 2s is surrounded by 1s.

`010
 121
 010`

means 2 surround by one.
there are some complicated like:

`10110
 21212
 11111`

the 2 is surround by 1 because (2,1) is surround by 1 and (0,1) is not surround by 1 because no 1 in the left of (0,1).

How to determine which contains which and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you implying the solution should be a BFS with your title?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: `the 2 is surround by 1 because (2,1) is surround by 1 and (0,1) is not surround by 1 because no 1 in the left of (0,1).` what is `(2,1)` ? a point in the grid?

Comment: (2,1) means cell in column 2, row 1. Column and row start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that table `a` with size m*n.
You should add a boundary around the table (like the following picture)
[image]

You can do simply like that:

- Assume you check position `(i,j)` of table is surrounded or not?
- BFS from `(i,j)` with condition `(a[u][v] == a[i][j] || a[u][v] == 0)` -> add `(u,v)` into stack
- if you visit a boundary (`a[0][x]`, `a[x][0]`, `a[m+1][x]`, `a[x][n+1]`) -> it is not surrounded